Jhipster oauth2 custom database oracle -
in my jhipster application i want these tables
JHI_AUTHORITY
JHI_PERSISTENT_TOKEN
JHI_USER
JHI_USER_AUTHORITY
to be made in my oracle database using oauth2 security if i use jwt it configures these tables in my changelog but if i choose oauth2 it doesn't configure these tables in my changelog
below are my yo.src.json file and changelog file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <!--
        JHipster core tables.
        The initial schema has the '00000000000001' id, so that it is over-written if we re-generate it.
    -->
    <changeSet id="00000000000001" author="jhipster">
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="jhipster" id="00000000000002" context="test">
        <createTable tableName="jhi_date_time_wrapper">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="jhi_date_time_wrapperPK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="instant" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="local_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="offset_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="zoned_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="local_time" type="time"/>
            <column name="offset_time" type="time"/>
            <column name="local_date" type="date"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>


{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "baseName": "r2Dbcwithgateway",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
    "clientFramework": "angular",
    "clientTestFrameworks": [],
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "creationTimestamp": 1716961599093,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "oracle",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entities": [],
    "feignClient": null,
    "gradleEnterpriseHost": null,
    "jhipsterVersion": "8.4.0",
    "jwtSecretKey": "NWM5NjAyYTQ2NDNkZjkwNmJmM2ViODgwMDg4NDQwZDdiYTBiODMwODEzNjllYzRkNjQ5ODkzMTg3NjZiYmRjYjc5MjEzN2U2NDAxMTk5ZDQ0ZDAzMzFjZjEyZDY3NWFkNTdkNDcxMzY3OWNkMjE4ZmI3OWQyZDNiZjFmZmQ2YWU=",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "microfrontend": false,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "prodDatabaseType": "oracle",
    "reactive": true,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": 8080,
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "syncUserWithIdp": null,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}


i tried numerous things but couldnt get my okta or keycloak to connect to my oracle database and make default tables of the security.

This happens because when you use OAuth 2.0, it's the responsibility of the identity provider to store the JWT tokens, not the JHipster application.
